Speed control of BLDC motor using Sliding mode control
It existe many control algorithms for speed control of a BLDC motor, recently I was reading a book proposing a sliding mode control for BLDC speed control with the following equations that a captured from the book:

here: state space equation of the system is given as follows:

What confused me is how the author directly linked the control input with the equivalent control input. What let him rewrite the control as that and did not keep it as Ueq ?
Ref: "PERMANENT MAGNET BRUSHLESS DC MOTOR DRIVES AND CONTROLS" by Chang liang Xia page:126.

Thanks for adding that. The book looks good. And costly :-(  .
